# Looping through list values in a command line statement in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, command-line-arguments

I have a .py file for my astrophysics research that gives me a list of target ids when I use the command line statement `my_file.py "Source Name"`. I want to be able to get this data in Jupyter notebook for many sources.

Within Jupyter notebook, I know I can get the output from the following command line argument:
 `results = ! python my_file.py "Source Name"`. However, I would like to be able to pythonically get results for all sources by looping through a list containing them.

I have already tried using list indices as shown below:

```
my_list = ['"Source 1"', '"Source 2"']
results_list = list()

for val in my_list:
    result = ! python my_file.py val
    results_list.append(result)
```

Here, it seems that the command line argument doesn't interpret val as a value in the list, but rather just reads it literally as 'val'. Is there a way to have jupyter notebook place the list value here?
I am admittedly new to using command line arguments, so any help/explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you can use something like `$val` - but I'd have to look up the exact character in the docs or a previous answer.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked! Thank you, so what do you call this $ symbol if I want to read more on its use?